# Url should be closed automatically on timeout

Tags: internet-explorer, winapi, visual-c++

My requirement is to close particular URL running on the web browser usinh win32 vc++ application. Let say In chrome we have opened facebook.com, gmail.com etc.My url is opened in the same chrome instance where all the facebook, gmail is opened. My application should close only the single tab in chrome where my desired URL is opened. I tried to find lot on net but was not able to find any method that can be used to close particular URl in the browser, without closing all other url.

Comment: Sounds like you should be writing a chrome extension. I'm unclear why you have tagged this question as you have.

Comment: @JonathanPotter it sounds like he wants a browser-agnostic solution, or at least one that runs on all browsers?

Comment: @Iggy Unfortunately this is something that is browser-specific. You will need to look up the APIs provided by each browser that you are targeting. You may very well need to write a browser extension, as Jonathan Potter indicated, and as such will need separate extensions for each browser. This is outside my personal expertise; sorry.